# Finding Similar columns in two dataframes using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have two `DataFrames` which has some data like this,

```
+-------+--------+------------------+---------+
|ADDRESS|CUSTOMER|      CUSTOMERTIME|   POL   |
+-------+--------+------------------+---------+
|  There|   cust0|3069.4768999023245|578596829|
|  There|   cust0|3069.4768999023245|43831451 |
|   Here|   cust1| 15.29206776391711|578596829|
|  There|   cust0|3069.4768999023245|43831451 |
|   Here|   cust1| 15.29206776391711|578596829|
|   Here|   cust4| 32.04741866436953|43831451 |
+-------+--------+------------------+---------+
```

and

```
 +---------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+
 |   POLICY|     POLICYENDTIME|   POLICYSTARTTIME|PVAR0|PVAR1|
 +---------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+
 |578596829|3599.3427299724353|13.433243831334922|    2|    0|
 |578596829|3599.3427299724353|13.433243831334922|    2|    0|
 | 43831451|3712.2672901111655|1744.9884452423225|    0|    6|
 |578596829|3599.3427299724353|13.433243831334922|    2|    0|
 | 43831451|3712.2672901111655|1744.9884452423225|    0|    6|
 | 43831451|3979.2754016079016|3712.2672901111655|    0|    5|
 +---------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+
```

now i want to compare this two data frames to find the matching column that i can join these `DataFrames` in the next step (In this case it would be `POLICY` and `POL`). Is there any algorithms or other ways that i can predict this?

Comment: Can it be in `pyspark` ?

Comment: @Bala i am looking for a way to find the column in two dataframes that i can join. So anything is welcome

Answer (score 2):

Given `df1` and `df2` you can find common columns through

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([('1',),('2',)]).toDF(['a'])
df2 = sc.parallelize([('1','2'),('2','3')]).toDF(['a','b'])

>>>set(df1.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns))
set(['a'])

>>>list(set(df1.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns)))
['a']
```

This should get the difference

```
>>> list(set(df1.columns).symmetric_difference(set(df2.columns)))
['b']
```

Comment: What if the column names are differet also ? i need something that can compare the data and predict the columns? I have edited my post to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Made changes to the answer. Code was wrong earlier.

Comment: This one will only provide if the column names are same ryt?. In my case there is no matching column names at all.

Comment: That would be too expensive and accuracy will be low if two columns have same value (e.g. first_name, last_name)